# SharePoint Online - Content Type Issue with Document Library in Modern Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library, modern-team-site, spo

I had created a content type using `Site Pages` as parent content type. I added site columns to this content type and finally created a new `Document Library` and added this content type to the library.

Now when I click on `+New` button, it shows me three options i.e. `Folder, My Derived Content Type and Link`. Now, on selecting `My Derived Content Type` option to create a new page in this library, it is redirecting me to the `SitePages` and creates a page in `SitePages` library instead.

Is anyone also facing the same issue? If so, do you know why this happening or any solution in this direction will be great help.

And yes, I am using SPO Dev Tenant, with preview feature option enabled.

**Edit**
Is it possible to provision modern pages anywhere other than `Site Pages` library? If no, what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue, it’s the default behavior that it links to the page in SitePages library when we create a new page with site page as  content type in the document library.

As a workaround, you can create a new content type which its parent content type is “Basic Page”. But the new page with Basic Page content type has no modern UI style.

Or you can copy the relevant pages to new document library and delete these pages SitePages library.

**Update:**

we can copy the page in Site Pages library through library classic experience.
exit modern experience in the library and right click the page, select copy and type the library URL.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but I am looking to take advantage of modern UI. I was just wondering, is it possible to provision Modern Page in any other library apart from `Site Pages`? I also tried copying the site page to other library, but it doesn't give you that option, the option available is to copy in sub folder in site pages library.

Comment: You can exit Modern experience in Site Pages library and right click the relevant page, select copy and type the relevant library you want the page you created to copy. You can check the update of the reply above.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I am planning to develop a solution where I am having 100s of pages and language translation of those pages. Its not a good idea to copy paste. I just want to know, can we provision content type derived from SitePages  content type in other libraries? I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply create a new pages library in SharePoint. A Site Pages library is more than just a document library with content types.  There are event receivers and other hooks all over the site that enable its functionality.  Pages libraries in the non-modern Publishing feature worked the same way.

I would advise against trying to hack or work around the limitation. Fighting the platform will cause you more grief than it solves.

What you should do instead is create new content types derived from Site Page, and add those to the provided Site Pages library.

Comment: If you read properly, I created a new custom type deriving from `Site Pages` content type, and trying to create a library based on my new content type. Now in modern site you don't have any option other than `Document Library` template. So I created a new document library, and added content type. But now, instead of creating a new document in this library, its create a document at SitePages library.

Comment: Also as I mentioned this is a dev tenant with first release option open, there are time when MS ship update and it break some functionality. One of the same functionality is, you cant upload a `.css` in `style library` on sharepoint online anymore, results in 500 internal error